# Размеры вложенных List в C#

Tags: c#, list

Пока писал диплом (использую вложенные `List < List<...>>` c кучей данных), понадобилось проверить, сколько элементов влезает в `List<double>`: оказалось, 33554432. В пересчёте (double - 8 байт) получается ровно 256 Мб памяти.

Далее я создал `List < List< double>>`: оказалось, что при максимальном количестве элементов внутреннего листа (всё те же 33554432) внешний лист успевает создать 3 внутренних - а потом происходит всё то же *`"System.OutOfMemoryException"`*. То есть, в `List< List<double>>` влезает уже 256 * 3 Мб.

А потом я создал всё тот же `List< List< double>>`, но при этом заполнял внутренний лист только на четверть от максимально возможного (33554432/4). Казалось бы, очевидно, что внешних листов должно получиться 12 (3 * 4=12) - но нет! Внешних листов создаётся 16. То есть, получается уже 256 * 4 Мб. А если заполнять внутренние количеством элементов (33554432/64), то внешних листов получается аж 265 (хотя 3 * 64=192) - то есть, 1060 Мб.

Уже ничего не понимая, я создал `List< List< List< double>>>`: при всё тех же максимально 33554432 элементах во внутреннем листе удаётся создать ровно два с половиной промежуточных листа -- после этого всё падает со всё тем же `Exception'ом`. То есть, получается 256 * 2,5 Мб.

---

Можете объяснить, как вообще выделяется память под `List`? И почему система не может занять пару гигабайт оперативки (у меня 4 Гб, х64), потом перейти в файл подкачки - и только потом откинуться со словами *`"System.OutOfMemoryException"`*? Зачем надо объявлять, что памяти больше нет, хотя её еще полно?

P.S. Если долго объяснять, посоветуйте что-нибудь почитать по этому поводу, если эти вещи где-то объяснены. Да, я чайник, знаю.

Всем спасибо!

Comment: ОС и ее разрядность требуется угадать?

(про 64-бит CPU я прочитал).

Comment: Чё-то вы не то померили. У меня вот такая программа

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            new List<double>(int.Parse(args[0]));
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fail");
        }
    }

выдаёт Success для аргумента 166723063 и меньше и Fail для больше.

Comment: У меня Win7 x64, проверял вот так, выводит "33554432".

            List<double> List1 = new List<double>();

            int counter1 = 0;

            try
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    List1.Add(0.1);
                    counter1++;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine(counter1);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

Comment: У меня выводит 67108864. Win8 32

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Число максимальных эелементов в списке будет зависеть от многих параметров. Но я просто попытаюсь объяснить, как выделяется память под эти элементы внутри класса `List<T>`.

`List<T>` - это ничто иное как обертка над обычным массивом `T[]`. Этот массив инициализируется при создании списка, либо инициализируется повторно уже в процессе работы с созданным списком. Первый случай довольно прост - это начальная инициализация, которая происходит при вызове конструкторов. Немного кода из класса `List<T>`:

```
private const int _defaultCapacity = 4;
private T[] _items;
static T[]  _emptyArray = new T[0];

// Constructs a List. The list is initially empty and has a capacity
// of zero. Upon adding the first element to the list the capacity is
// increased to 16, and then increased in multiples of two as required.
public List() {
    _items = _emptyArray;
}

// Constructs a List with a given initial capacity. The list is
// initially empty, but will have room for the given number of elements
// before any reallocations are required.
public List(int capacity) {
    if (capacity < 0)
         ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.capacity,
             ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_SmallCapacity);
    _items = new T[capacity];
}
```

Второй случай может произойти во время добавления в список новых элементов или при присвоении нового значение свойству `Capacity`. Рассмотрим случай с добавлением новых элементов. Из комментария над первым конструктором видно, что размер внутреннего массива **увеличивается вдвое**. Происходит это тогда, когда текущий массив уже полностью занят элементами. Соответствующий код:

```
// Gets and sets the capacity of this list.  The capacity is the size of
// the internal array used to hold items.  When set, the internal
// array of the list is reallocated to the given capacity.
public int Capacity {
    get { return _items.Length; }
    set {
        if (value != _items.Length) {
            if (value < _size) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.value,
                    ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_SmallCapacity);
            }

            if (value > 0) {
                T[] newItems = new T[value];
                if (_size > 0) {
                    Array.Copy(_items, 0, newItems, 0, _size);
                }
                _items = newItems;
            }
            else {
                _items = _emptyArray;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Ensures that the capacity of this list is at least the given minimum
// value. If the currect capacity of the list is less than min, the
// capacity is increased to twice the current capacity or to min,
// whichever is larger.
private void EnsureCapacity(int min) {
    if (_items.Length < min) {
        int newCapacity = _items.Length == 0 ? _defaultCapacity : _items.Length * 2;
        if (newCapacity < min) newCapacity = min;
        Capacity = newCapacity;
    }
}
```

Метод `EnsureCapacity` вызывается внутри всех методов списка, добавляющих в него новые элементы (`Add()`, `Insert()` и т.д.).

Какой из этого всего можно сделать вывод? Во время добавления элементов в список наступают моменты, когда памяти под элементы выделено в 3 раза больше, чем требуется на самом деле (момент, когда создался новый, в 2 раза больший массив и в него копируются данные из старого массива).

Исходники смотрел здесь: [.NET List sources](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Generic/List@cs/2/List@cs)

Comment: Это очень хороший ответ

Comment: @Fike, спасибо!

Comment: Про фрагментацию-то бы подробнее написали. Ну и ответ можно дополнить этим постом: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/